# Correct way to measure change over a given time period for rates

Tags: time-series, inference, epidemiology, incidence-rate-ratio

I have data on the number of donors each year as well as the size of the total population each year and the number of deaths each year as well as the number of patients that have died on a intensive care unit.

To be considered as a donor the patient has to die on a intensive care unit.

Im considering calculating a crude rate for each year but...

**First question.**

Which population would best serve as the denominator in this case, total population, number of deaths or number of deaths on a intensive care unit?

**Second question.**

How can I tell if the number of donors have increased or decreased over a given time period? The actual number of donors might have increased but so could the number of deaths in the population which would have an effect on the number of donors each year. Would constructing a 95% CI around each rate for each year be a possible way? Or should I compute incidence rate ratio comparing different years?

**Third question.**

I have data on 10 years. In year 5 a new regulation took effect which enabled more patients to become donors. How can I take this regulation into account? Is the change in number of donors each year only because of the new regulation?